# Jquery: Canvas Pie Timer plugin, how to to it: if the interval timer is currently active, don't activate again?

Tags: jquery, canvas, timer, intervals

http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/NvVu7/

When the pie timer is active and counting down, and you start it again, it messes up and starts flickering and then the callback is endlessly activated.

Is there a way to add a check to the plugin, that says "if this interval exists/is running, don't start it again, if it isn't running, then start it."?

You can try clicking 'load a large file' in the demo, to start the pie timer multiple times and see how it acts.

// Jquery pie timer plugin

```
(function( $ ){

    jQuery.fn.pietimer = function( options, callback ) {

        var settings = {
            'seconds': 10,
            'colour': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
            'height': this.height(),
            'width': this.width()
        };

        if ( options ) { 
            $.extend( settings, options );
        }


        this.html('<canvas id="pie_timer" width="'+settings.height+'" height="'+settings.height+'"></canvas>');

        var val = 360;

        interval = setInterval(timer, 40);

        function timer(){

            var canvas = document.getElementById('pie_timer'); 

            if (canvas.getContext){

                val -= ( 360 / settings.seconds ) / 24;

                if ( val <= 0 ){

                    clearInterval(interval);
                    canvas.width = canvas.width;
                    if(typeof callback == 'function'){
                        callback.call();

                    }

                } else {

                    canvas.width = canvas.width;

                    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                    var canvas_size = [canvas.width, canvas.height];
                    var radius = Math.min(canvas_size[0], canvas_size[1]) / 2;
                    var center = [canvas_size[0]/2, canvas_size[1]/2];

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(center[0], center[1]);
                    var start = ( 3 * Math.PI ) / 2;
                    ctx.arc(
                        center[0],
                        center[1],
                        radius,
                        start - val * ( Math.PI / 180 ),
                        start,
                        false
                    );

                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = settings.colour;
                    ctx.fill();

                }

            }

        }

        return this;

    };
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just add an alreadyClicked var? That will stop it from activating again.

http://jsfiddle.net/NvVu7/6/

Comment: i would prefer having it in the plugin, because i'll have to use the 'alreadyclicked' multiple times on the website, repeating myself in the code, but if we can't figure out how to do it in the plugin, then this works.